# Creating and Rotating Raster Dataset using ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, raster, esri-geodatabase

I'm following the "How to create a raster dataset" tutorial: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000464000000

The questions are:

1) How can I create the raster in a file geodatabase? (The example given is incomplete.)

2) How can I rotate the newly created raster? (Standalone TIFF or a geodatabase raster.)

I know there is IRasterGeometryProc3, but I can't make it work.

Comment: I couldn't find in which point you think the example is incomplete. Can you make it more clear? May be then I can help you

Comment: You're right, the example is sufficient, already gone through this. I don't remember exactly what I was missing, despite some tips on how to rotate the raster. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. It may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, it creates a raster in a raster workspace. If you need a file geodatabase, you need to create/open a file geodatabase and then assign it to a raster workspace and all others are same procedure then.

**ADDITION:**
You can go through [IRasterGeometryProc.Rotate Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001q000002v4000000)

I found following code snippet in a [esri document](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/62937a09-b1c5-47d7-a1ac-f7a5daab3c89.htm). Though this document for arcgis version 9.2, it may help you.

```
void Rotate(IRaster raster)
{
    IRasterGeometryProc rasterGP = new RasterGeometryProcClass();
    rasterGP.Rotate(null, 45, raster);
    rasterGP.Register(raster);
}
```